# how to run composer install on the server cpanel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, cpanel

I have successfully uploaded my symfony app to the server. I have also copied the content of the web folder into the public_html folder of my website. But when I access my app via the www.domain.com I get this error

```
Warning: require_once(/home/domain/public_html/../app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/domain/public_html/app.php on line 6

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/domain/public_html/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/domain/public_html/app.php on line 6
```

After researching I found that you can run composer install on the server but my challenge is that I dont know how to run cli command on the server via ssh/cpanel.

Please who will be kind enough to show me the way. This is my first attempt on trying to host a symfony application

Answer (score 0):

When you don't run an composer install your dependencies are missing and the `bootstrap.cache.php` isn't created. So you have to upload the file and the complete vendor folder.

But i would prefer to take a look at your SSH connection and use the correct way. Otherwise you have to upload every time your complete sources including your vendor folder which can take a lot of time.

And the next think is your path. The components from your Symfony application are normally outside of your webroot. So you have to be sure that you can access that folders outside your webroot.

In some systems you have to allow that before you can use it. Otherwise you have to upload your complete application to your `public_html` folder and put your domain to the `web` subdirectory.

Comment: I have copied all the projects into the public_html folder of my project and still it did not work